# Error: fluent.14.5.7 UDF (SEGMENTATION VIOLATION)

Tags: c, fluent

I'm using Fluent 14.5.7 and I have some programming error while using my UDF.
The simulation I'm trying to solve is a desulfurization process in an horizontal fixed bed reactor. It works perfectly before including the UDF with the reactions (between CaO and SO2).
I've tried changing some parameters, returning a constant value (replacing *rr=60*k*Beta*NSO2 with *rr=60), and some others things, but the same error appeared.

Here is my C code:

```
/*********************************************************************/
#include "udf.h"
#include "sg_mphase.h"
DEFINE_HET_RXN_RATE(SO2_capture , c, t, hr, mw,yi, rr, rr_t)
{
Thread **pt = THREAD_SUB_THREADS(t);
Thread *tg = pt[0];
Thread *ts = pt[1];
real XCaO = C_YI(c,ts,0); /* Para checkear que hay sorbente*/
real XSO2 = C_YI(c,tg,0); /* Fraccion masica SO2 en la fase gas*/
real mwSO2 = 64.0638;
real DENS_Gas = C_R(c,tg); /* Si hay problemas se puede considerar que es constante*/
real VReac=6333.843; /* Volumen total del reactor en cm³ */
real NSO2 = XSO2 / mwSO2 * DENS_Gas * VReac; /* Controla el valor de NSO2 */
real Time_min = CURRENT_TIME / 60;

/*valores de constantes a 400ºC */

real EDiff = -49300; /*mejor sacar el negativo de la potencia*/
real aa1 = 2.10e-03;
real aa2 = 12.9e-02;
real aa3 = -0.66;  /*mejor sacar el negativo de la potencia*/
real kdiff = aa1 * exp (EDiff/(8.314 * C_T(c,t))) * (1 + aa2 * exp (aa3*Time_min));
real aa4 = 0.82;
real aa5 = -1;  /*mejor sacar el negativo de la potencia*/
real Beta = (1 - aa4 * exp (aa5*Time_min));
real k0 = 1.78e-02;
real Ea = -13900;  /*mejor sacar el negativo de la potencia*/
real ks = k0 * exp (Ea/(8.314 * C_T(c,t)));
real k = (ks * kdiff)/(ks + kdiff);
if (XCaO != 0)
{
     *rr = 60 * k * Beta * NSO2;    
}
else 
{
     *rr = 0;   
}
/*return;*/
}

/****************************************************************/
```

When I run my simulation, it apperead the following error:

```
===============================================================================
Stack backtrace generated for process id 27426 on signal 1 :
1000000: /usr/local/ansys_inc/v154/fluent/fluent14.5.7/lnamd64/2ddp/fluent.14.5.7 [0x166a164]
1000000: /usr/local/ansys_inc/v154/fluent/fluent14.5.7/lnamd64/2ddp/fluent.14.5.7 [0x166a8d3]
1000000: /lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0x3736e0eca0]
1000000: Kin_Sulp_3/lnamd64/2ddp/libudf.so(SO2_capture+0x9b) [0x2afee78f644f]
Check the file fluenterror.log for details.
Please include this information with any bug report you file on this issue!
===============================================================================

Error: fluent.14.5.7 received a fatal signal (SEGMENTATION VIOLATION).
Error Object: #f
```

The fluenterror.log file gives the following information:

```
Received signal 1 [time 5/21/14 13:23:5]
1000000: /usr/local/ansys_inc/v145/fluent/fluent14.5.7/lnamd64/2ddp/fluent.14.5.7 [0x166a287]
1000000: /usr/local/ansys_inc/v145/fluent/fluent14.5.7/lnamd64/2ddp/fluent.14.5.7 [0x166a8d3]
1000000: /lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0x3736e0eca0]
1000000: Kin_Sulp_3/lnamd64/2ddp/libudf.so(SO2_capture+0x9b) [0x2afee78f644f]

Error [client] [time 5/21/14 13:23:6] fluent.14.5.7 received a fatal signal (SEGMENTATION VIOLATION).
999999:/usr/local/ansys_inc/v145/fluent/fluent14.5.7/lnamd64/2ddp/fluent.14.5.7(CX_Primitive_Error+0x204) [0x166a704]
999999: /usr/local/ansys_inc/v145/fluent/fluent14.5.7/lnamd64/2ddp/fluent.14.5.7 [0x166a91f]
999999: /lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0x3736e0eca0]
999999: Kin_Sulp_3/lnamd64/2ddp/libudf.so(SO2_capture+0x9b) [0x2afee78f644f]
```

Any suggestion will be appreciate and if you need any more information I'll be glad to give it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I am also working in fluent , wannt to make a UDF for dynamic mesh, so need a udf.h header file for C++. 
I got one from google. but it shows lots of error:

```
 /* $OpenBSD: udf.h,v 1.20 2014/11/18 10:42:15 dlg Exp $    */

    /*
     * Copyright (c) 2001, 2002 Scott Long <scottl@freebsd.org>
     * All rights reserved.
     *
     * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
     * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
     * are met:
     * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
     *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
     * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
     *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
     *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
     *
     * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE AUTHOR AND CONTRIBUTORS ``AS IS'' AND
     * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
     * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
     * ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
     * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
     * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS
     * OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
     * HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
     * LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY
     * OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF
     * SUCH DAMAGE.
     *
     * $FreeBSD: src/sys/fs/udf/udf.h,v 1.9 2004/10/29 10:40:58 phk Exp $
     */

    /*
     * Ported to OpenBSD by Pedro Martelletto in February 2005.
     */

    #define UDF_HASHTBLSIZE 100
    #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <fstream>

    #define u_diroff    un_u.u_diroff
    #define u_vatlen    un_u.u_vatlen

    typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;
    typedef uint32_t udfino_t;

    struct unode {
        struct LIST_ENTRY *u_le;
        struct vnode *u_vnode;
        struct vnode *u_devvp;
        struct umount *u_ump;
        struct lock u_lock;
        dev_t u_dev;
        udfino_t u_ino;
        union {
            long u_diroff;
            long u_vatlen;
        } un_u;
        struct extfile_entry *u_fentry;
    };

    struct umount {
        int um_flags;
        struct mount *um_mountp;
        struct vnode *um_devvp;
        dev_t um_dev;
        int um_bsize;
        int um_bshift;
        int um_bmask;
        uint32_t um_start;
        uint32_t um_realstart;
        uint32_t um_len;
        uint32_t um_reallen;
        uint32_t um_meta_start;
        uint32_t um_meta_len;
        struct unode *um_vat;
        struct long_ad um_root_icb;
        LIST_HEAD(udf_hash_lh, unode) *um_hashtbl;
        SIPHASH_KEY um_hashkey;
        u_long um_hashsz;
        struct mutex um_hashmtx;
        int um_psecs;
        int um_stbl_len;
        struct udf_sparing_table *um_stbl;
    };

    #define UDF_MNT_FIND_VAT    0x01    /* Indicates a VAT must be found */
    #define UDF_MNT_USES_VAT    0x02    /* Indicates a VAT must be used */
    #define UDF_MNT_USES_META   0x04    /* Indicates we are using a Metadata partition*/

    #define VTOU(vp)    ((struct unode *)((vp)->v_data))

    #ifdef _KERNEL

    struct udf_dirstream {
        struct unode    *node;
        struct umount   *ump;
        struct buf  *bp;
        uint8_t     *data;
        uint8_t     *buf;
        int     fsize;
        int     off;
        int     this_off;
        int     offset;
        int     size;
        int     error;
        int     fid_fragment;
    };

    #define VFSTOUDFFS(mp)  ((struct umount *)((mp)->mnt_data))

    /*
     * The block layer refers to things in terms of 512 byte blocks by default.
     * btodb() is expensive, so speed things up.
     * Can the block layer be forced to use a different block size?
     */
    #define RDSECTOR(devvp, sector, size, bp) \
        bread(devvp, \
            ((daddr_t)(sector) << ump->um_bshift) / DEV_BSIZE, size, bp)

    static __inline int
    udf_readlblks(struct umount *ump, int sector, int size, struct buf **bp)
    {
        return (RDSECTOR(ump->um_devvp, sector,
                 (size + ump->um_bmask) & ~ump->um_bmask, bp));
    }

    /*
     * Produce a suitable file number from an ICB.  The passed in ICB is expected
     * to be in little endian (meaning that it hasn't been swapped for big
     * endian machines yet).
     * If the fileno resolves to 0, we might be in big trouble.
     * Assumes the ICB is a long_ad.  This struct is compatible with short_ad,
     *     but not ext_ad.
     */
    static __inline udfino_t
    udf_getid(struct long_ad *icb)
    {
        return (letoh32(icb->loc.lb_num));
    }

    int udf_allocv(struct mount *, struct vnode **, struct proc *);
    int udf_hashlookup(struct umount *, udfino_t, int, struct vnode **);
    int udf_hashins(struct unode *);
    int udf_hashrem(struct unode *);
    int udf_checktag(struct desc_tag *, uint16_t);

    typedef uint16_t unicode_t;

    #endif /* _KERNEL */

the following are error:
Error   1   error C2079: 'unode::u_lock' uses undefined struct 'lock'   h:\5990\cfd validation\rcm\sample udf file\velocity\velocity\velocity\udf.h 57  1   VELOCITY
Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'  h:\5990\cfd validation\rcm\sample udf file\velocity\velocity\velocity\udf.h 61  1   VELOCITY
Error   3   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'  h:\5990\cfd validation\rcm\sample udf file\velocity\velocity\velocity\udf.h 61  1   VELOCITY
Error   4   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'  h:\5990\cfd validation\rcm\sample udf file\velocity\velocity\velocity\udf.h 62  1   VELOCITY
Error   5   error C2086: 'long unode::<unnamed-tag>::un_u' : redefinition   h:\5990\cfd validation\rcm\sample udf file\velocity\velocity\velocity\udf.h 62  1   VELOCITY
Error   6   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'  h:\5990\cfd validation\rcm\sample udf file\velocity\velocity\velocity\udf.h 62  1   VELOCITY
Error   7   error C2079: 'umount::um_root_icb' uses undefined struct 'long_ad'  h:\5990\cfd validation\rcm\sample udf file\velocity\velocity\velocity\udf.h 82  1   VELOCITY
Error   8   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'udf_hash_lh'    h:\5990\cfd validation\rcm\sample udf file\velocity\velocity\velocity\udf.h 83  1   VELOCITY
Error   9   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  h:\5990\cfd validation\rcm\sample udf file\velocity\velocity\velocity\udf.h 83  1   VELOCITY
Error   10  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   h:\5990\cfd validation\rcm\sample udf file\velocity\velocity\velocity\udf.h 83  1   VELOCITY
Warning 11  warning C4183: 'LIST_HEAD': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'    h:\5990\cfd validation\rcm\sample udf file\velocity\velocity\velocity\udf.h 83  1   VELOCITY
Error   12  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'um_hashkey'  h:\5990\cfd validation\rcm\sample udf file\velocity\velocity\velocity\udf.h 84  1   VELOCITY
Error   13  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   h:\5990\cfd validation\rcm\sample udf file\velocity\velocity\velocity\udf.h 84  1   VELOCITY
Error   14  error C2079: 'umount::um_hashmtx' uses undefined struct 'mutex' h:\5990\cfd validation\rcm\sample udf file\velocity\velocity\velocity\udf.h 86  1   VELOCITY
```

Comment: I can't tell if above code is a solution to this problem, but if it shows errors it's clearly not the one the asking person was looking for. Please improve you answer and test it before posting, also constrain yourself from posting a email address multiple times in the answers, it belongs in the comment section.